# Mat icon dynamically created based on state

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

in my app i display list of appeals, with their status (which is displayed using mat icon). Here is piece of my template

```
<div class="approve-detail" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <p>Created: {{absDetail?.reqDate|date:'d. L. y HH:mm'}}</p>
      <ng-container *ngIf="absDetail?.defList">
        <mat-list >
          <mat-list-item class="def-item" *ngFor="let def of absDetail.defList">
            <mat-icon matListIcon *ngIf="def.idReject!=0" class="warn" matTooltip="Rejected">thumb_down</mat-icon >
            <mat-icon matListIcon *ngIf="def.idApprove!=0&&def.idReject==0" class="success" matTooltip="Approved">thumb_up</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon matListIcon *ngIf="def.idReject==0 && def.idApprove==0" matTooltip="Waiting">help</mat-icon>
            <p matLine>{{def.name}}</p>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
        <mat-list *ngIf="abs | isDeleteAppealed:absDetail.defList">
          <mat-list-item class="def-item" *ngFor="let def of absDetail.defList">
            <mat-icon matListIcon *ngIf="def.idCancel<0" color="warn" matTooltip="Rejected">thumb_down</mat-icon >
            <mat-icon matListIcon *ngIf="def.idCancel>0" class="success" matTooltip="Approved">thumb_up</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon matListIcon *ngIf="def.idCancel==0" matTooltip="waiting">help</mat-icon>
            <p matLine>{{def.name}}</p>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```

It works, but its kinda dirty with all that ng-ifs, is there any more elegant way to do this? I was thinking about pipe, but i need to generate three dynamic properties for each element: class, tooltip and proper icon name, so it doesnt seems like a better solution. Any ideas? What about some kind of directive?

Comment: I like ngSwitch.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could do is wrap them in a separate component. Use your **let def** as an @Input() parameter. When it gets set, you can automatically change the value of the class/tooltip/icon. Something like this:

abs-icon.component.ts

```
imports...

@Component({
    selector: 'abs-icon',
    templateUrl: './abs-icon.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./abs-icon.component.css']
})
export class AbsIconComponent implements OnInit {
    
    public cls: string;
    public tooltip: string;
    public icont: string;

    private _abs: any;

    get abs(): any{
        return this._abs;
    }
    @Input() set abs(value: any) {
        this._abs = value;

        if (_abs.idReject != 0) {
            cls = "warn";
            tooltip = "Rejected";
            icont = "thumb_down"
        }
        else if (.......do the rest){
            /* some code */
        }
    }

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

abs-icon.component.html

```
<mat-icon matListIcon 
    class="{{cls}}" 
    [matTooltip]="tooltip">

{{icon}}

</mat-icon >
```

using it:

```
<abs-icon [abs]="def"> </abs-icon>
```